# Message: Unable to process binding Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I have created a custom module of One Step Checkout for the site. It's working fine till Magneto 2.4.2. But in Magento 2.4.3 when I try to access the checkout page using my extension I am getting **Message: Unable to process binding** errors in the console also Billing and Shipping Address section not loading.
[image]

Comment: Unsure but I think you should check your code related to getRegion as this issue come mainly when ko don't get the function name mention

Comment: Thank you for your response @NileshDubey. getRegion is default Magento function.